# Python method for finding a substring within a string

Tags: python, arcpy

I converted a KML to a feature class and no longer have access to the symbology set in the original KML.  I'm trying to re-create this by creating a new field that stores identifying information useful in creating the layer symbology.

There are three different 'keywords' in the original attribute table that would be useful in a control structure that determines the appropriate symbology type.  I need to search the string for these keywords, but I'm having trouble.

**The sample code below is just to get the control structure working -- I know I need to use an update cursor to change / add field addtributes.**

Here is my code:

```
# Import ESRI Python module
import arcpy

# Declare variables used in this script
#featureClass = r'C:\arbitraryLocationOnDisk'
oldField = 'FolderPath'
newField = 'HabitatType' # Restricted by domain: HabitatType
                            #  1. Critical Habitat
                            #  2. Corridors and Key Habitat Areas
                            #  3. Global IBA's

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureClass)
    for row in rows:
        fieldValue = row.getValue(oldField)

        if fieldValue.find('Global'):
            print 'Global IBA'
        elif fieldValue.find('Corridors'):
            print 'Corridors and Key Habbitat Areas'
        elif fieldValue.find('Critical'):
            print 'Critical Habitat'
        else:
            print 'Unrecognized habitat type: ' + fieldValue
        del fieldValue
except:
    arcpy.GetMessages()
finally:
    del rows
```

**The problem I'm experiencing is that after every single row, I'm getting 'Global IBA' despite the fact that not every row contains the substring 'Global'.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you're getting 'Global IBA' for every row is that Python's [string.find()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find) method returns an integer representing the substring's position within the string, not a boolean. When it can't find the substring, it returns -1, which evaluates to True in your if statement. This could also have the opposite effect; if the string begins with the specified substring, it will return zero, which evaluates to False in your if condition.

Here are some examples:

```
>>>> 'Global IBA'.find('Global')
0
>>>> bool('Global IBA'.find('Global'))
False
>>>> 'Global IBA'.find('gibberish')
-1
>>>> bool('Global IBA'.find('gibberish'))
True
```

Since you don't care about the substring's index, it's simpler just to use the 'in' operator:

```
if 'Global' in fieldValue:
    print 'Global IBA'
elif 'Corridors' in fieldValue:
    print 'Corridors and Key Habbitat Areas'
elif 'Critical' in fieldValue:
    print 'Critical Habitat'
else:
    print 'Unrecognized habitat type: ' + fieldValue
```

Answer (score 3):

[find()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find) returns -1 if no match is found (invalid index of the substring you searched for), so you should be checking against that. In other words, it doesn't have a boolean return value.

Eg. `if fieldValue.find('Global') > -1:` and so on.