# Symbology issue with feature class limited by domain

Tags: arcmap, symbology

I added a field to a feature class in order to maintain symbology from the original KML file (this is a new question [following up on this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27308/python-method-for-finding-a-substring-within-a-string)).  The new field is limited to three options by a **domain**.

When I go to symbolize based on this field, all values are considered to be  as opposed to being separated into their appropriate category.  Does this have to do with being controled by a coded domain or is something else going on here?
[image: Undesired Symbology Result]

Comment: No definition query: I've updated the image to include the count -- all of the features are considered <all other values> instead of their category defined in the Habitat Type field.

Comment: Roy, it might be a better idea to take the update you added with your code out of your question, and instead add it as an answer to your own question.  You can then mark it as accepted.  This way, someone searching for something similar will be able to see that the question has been answered and might solve their problem.

Comment: I was hoping Jakub was reformatting his answer so he could get credit, but I'll go ahead and do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update (Credit Jakub):

I changed my code (exerpt shown below); changing from a string (the domain index's description) to the index itself (integer) rectified the problem.

**Original Code:**

```
for row in rows:
    fieldValue = row.getValue(oldField)

    if fieldValue.find('IBA') > -1:
        row.setValue(newField, "Global IBA\'s")
```

**Updated Code:**

```
for row in rows:
    fieldValue = row.getValue(oldField)

    if fieldValue.find('IBA') > -1:
        row.setValue(newField, 2) # This is the coded domain for "Global IBA's"
```

**Note:** Even after changing the code the the integer index, the label still appears in the attribute table.